# Replace XML node to empty and add xsi:nil through SQL

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML column with specific nodes that I will like to update.

There is this node which I need to set to **null**.

Here is how I am updating the XML values at the moment:

```
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/House/Rooms/RoomSize/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewRoomSize")');
```

This statement will result in `<RoomSize> {Value} </RoomSize>`

How should I set such a value result in : `<RoomSize xsi:nil = "true" />`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

To **add the 'xsi:nil' attribute** to respective XML node:

```
SET @XML.modify('insert attribute xsi:nil {"true"} into (/House/Rooms/RoomSize)[1]');
```

To **remove the value** in current node (if present):

```
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/House/Rooms/RoomSize/text())[1] with ""');
```