# How to remove XML attribute [xsi:nil "true"] for a tag and insert text for the same tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, xml.modify

I want to remove the attribute `xsi:nil "true"` for `GeographicalLimit` tag and I need to enter some dummy text for the same using SQL

Current XML:

```
<Header>
    <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
    <GeographicalLimit xsi:nil="true" />
    <SampleTag> text </SampleTag>
</Header>
```

I need to change it to this XML:

```
<Header>
    <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
    <GeographicalLimit>Sample text</GeographicalLimit>
    <SampleTag> text </SampleTag>
</Header>
```

I want to achieve the reverse of this
[Replace XML node to empty and add xsi:nil through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914339/replace-xml-node-to-empty-and-add-xsinil-through-sql)

Comment: Please add your DBMS tag and add more sample data (entire XML)

Comment: @astentx. I have added the XML.

Comment: I want to do the reverse of this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914339/replace-xml-node-to-empty-and-add-xsinil-through-sql

Comment: What is your DBMS? Each of them has its own SQL implementation. From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info: *In addition to sql, also provide the relevant rdbms tag (i.e. sql-server, oracle, postgresql), and the lowest version you need the solution. Remember - different products use different dialects of SQL, and this can have a drastic effect on the answers you might get.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using MS SQL Server.

First, your XML sample is not **well-formed** because there is no namespace declaration with the *xsi* prefix. So, we need to fix it by adding such namespace declaration to the root.

The rest is a two step process:

1. Insert text value to a nil element.
2. Delete @xsi:nil attribute in the XML element.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, report XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (report) VALUES
(N'<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
    <GeographicalLimit xsi:nil="true"/>
    <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
</Header>');
-- DDL and data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @var VARCHAR(20) = 'Sample text';

-- Step #1
UPDATE @tbl
SET report.modify('insert text {sql:variable("@var")} as first into (/Header/GeographicalLimit)[1]')
WHERE report.exist('/Header/GeographicalLimit[text()]') = 0;

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- Step #2
UPDATE @tbl
SET report.modify('delete /Header/GeographicalLimit[text()]/@xsi:nil');

-- final
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Final Output**

```
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
  <GeographicalLimit>Sample text</GeographicalLimit>
  <SampleTag>text</SampleTag>
</Header>
```